# How do I get php ini-value in github actions to point towards a file in my project directory

Tags: php, github-actions

Here's my .yml file for github actions. How do I correctly add the `ini-values` parameter to point to a directory in my project? My project structure is `InstaGetSymfony/src` = symfony MVC dir.

I want my `curl.cainfo` ini value to point towards `InstaGetSymfony/ca/cacert.pem`

```
name: InstaGet

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  run:
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout codebase
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup PHP with pecl extension
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: '7.4'
        tools: pecl
        extensions: curl
        ini-values: curl.cainfo=/home/runner/work/InstaGetSymfony/InstaGetSymfony/ca/cacert.pem

    - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
      run: composer validate

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: composer install

    - name: Run phing
      run: vendor/bin/phing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the directory in a previous step and use that.

```yaml
- name: Get current directory
  id: pwd
  run: echo "::set-output name=pwd::$(pwd)"

- name: Setup PHP
  uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
  with:
    php-version: '7.4'
    ini-values: curl.cainfo=${{ steps.pwd.outputs.pwd }}/ca/cacert.pem
```

Also curl extension is available by default and pecl is not needed for this workflow, so you can remove those.